# Alternative to VS for editing RS reports?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

VS works I guess, but it's definitely pretty clunky in a lot of ways, and I was just wondering if there was some third-party alternative that's better.

Answer (score 1):

How about the first version of report builder? That was designed as a stripped down tool that is easy to use without all the "bloat" of visual studio

Comment: Report Builder is fairly good for "power user" level, but not developers. And it still requires (IMO) someone familiar with databases behind the scenes to set up report models.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of, at least in the general case.  There are third party tools that will spit out .rdl files that can be used by SSRS, but none I'm aware of that act as a general purpose .rdl editor.